# Convert image format on Cloud Storage with Cloud Functions and Sharp does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, sharp

When uploading an image to Firebase Cloud Storage, I want to resize and convert the image format to webp.  So I created a trigger with Cloud Function. To do this, I am using Node.js Sharp library.

The Cloud Function resizes the image correctly, **but it always keeps me the original format.**

This is the code for the conversion and resize:

```js
function resize(originalFile, resizedFile, size) {
  let height, width;
  if (size.indexOf(",") !== -1) {
    [width, height] = size.split(",");
  } else if (size.indexOf("x") !== -1) {
    [width, height] = size.split("x");
  } else {
    throw new Error("height and width are not delimited by a ',' or a 'x'");
  }
  return sharp(originalFile)
    .rotate()
    .toFormat("webp", {
      quality: 80,
      force: true
    })
    .resize(parseInt(width, 10), parseInt(height, 10), {
      fit: "inside",
      withoutEnlargement: true,
    }).toFile(resizedFile);
}
```

Running on a node.js project locally, it works fine.

**UPDATE**

I'm using Sharp 0.26.1, I also tried previous versions as suggested, but nothing has changed.

I tried this too, using the fs-extra library to write the file, but the result is still the same: resize and compression work correctly, while format conversion does not.

```js
async function resize(originalFile, resizedFile, size) {
  let height, width;
  if (size.indexOf(",") !== -1) {
    [width, height] = size.split(",");
  }
  else if (size.indexOf("x") !== -1) {
    [width, height] = size.split("x");
  }
  else {
    throw new Error("height and width are not delimited by a ',' or a 'x'");
  }


  const data = await sharp(originalFile)
    .rotate()
    .toFormat("webp")
    .resize(parseInt(width, 10), parseInt(height, 10), {
      fit: "inside",
      withoutEnlargement: true,
    })
    .webp({
      quality: 80,
      force: true
    })
    //.toFile(resizedFile);
    .toBuffer();
    fs.writeFileSync(resizedFile, data);

}
```

Again, launching the code locally, it works fine. (When I say "locally" I mean on a node.js project. It is not possible to test this Cloud Function locally, because there is no official Cloud Storage local emulator)

Answer (score 2):

I have been battling with this for hours and this is what finally worked for me. Make sure the mimetype you are setting with the upload header you are using for uploading to AWS/Azure/Digital Ocean is 'image/webp'

Comment: This looks more like a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using only `toFormat()` try using it followed by the `webp()` call, like this:

```
return sharp(originalFile)
    .rotate()
    .resize(parseInt(width, 10), parseInt(height, 10), {
        fit: "inside",
        withoutEnlargement: true,
    })
    .toFormat("webp")
    .webp({
        quality: 80,
        force: true
    });
    .toFile(resizedFile);
```

This should make it work.

Comment: I had already tried, I tried it again, but it doesn't work. I thought the problem might be "webp", but with other formats it doesn't work too.

Comment: How are you calling the function? `.toFile(resizedFile)` returns a promise, so it might be an synchronicity issue.

Comment: The function is called synchronously (with the expression "await").  In fact, the resize works correctly.  Could it be a problem related to the import of sharp library?  Or an operating system problem?

Comment: I would say that you doing everything correctly in your code then, and that the issue is likely to be in the sharp library itself, try using a different version of it as a test.

Comment: I've tried newer and older versions, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried to convert the image format with another library (webp-converter), but the result is always the same: the image is compressed but the format is not converted. At this point I would say that there is something wrong or something I'm ignoring about Functions.

Comment: Try disabling cache writing the following line before calling sharp in your function: `sharp.cache(false);`

Comment: Even disabling the cache, it doesn't work. It seems that it totally ignores conversion. I tried to remove the resize command, well: it does the compression but not the conversion.

Comment: This might be a long shot, but try the code I edited into the answer, I changed this to keep a structure of image processing -> file formating -> output.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. To test only file formating, I also tried to exclude resizing, but it doesn't work. Anyway, thank you very much for your help and comments. This thing is driving me crazy man.

Comment: No problem, glad to help, I will keep looking for solutions to this issue but meanwhile you could try to contact [GCP support](https://cloud.google.com/support) so they can inspect your project to check if there is anything wrong with it. Also, have you checked if there are any errors being throwed in the Cloud Function's Logs? There could some relevant information there. Here is the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging) for logging with Cloud Functions

Comment: Yes, I used the logs to figure out if something went wrong, but there is no error, this is just the strange thing. Meanwhile I will try to contact GCP support, thanks.